powershell 5.1, how to use -TargetTypeForDeserialization in Update-TypeData?
I create a class
class myMessage {

    [datetime]$WhenCreatedUTC
    
    [string]$name
    [string]$text
}

then add a computed value
Update-TypeData -TypeName myMessage -MemberType ScriptProperty -MemberName WhenCreated -Value { $this.WhenCreatedUTC.toLocalTime() } -Force

then, as people usually do not like UTC time, I hide the core property WhenCretadUTC
Update-TypeData -TypeName myMessage -DefaultDisplayPropertySet WhenCreated,name,text -Force

but I want only the core propeterties to be saves by Export-CliXml
Update-TypeData -TypeName myMessage -SerializationMethod SpecificProperties -PropertySerializationSet WhenCreatedUTC,name,text -Force

I now create an occurrence of the class and export it
$m1 = [myMessage]@{WhenCreatedUTC=[datetime]::utcnow;Name='myName';Text='myText'}
$m1 | Export-CliXml message.xml

the CliXml contains what expected
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>myMessage</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>myMessage</ToString>
    <Props>
      <DT N="WhenCreatedUTC">2024-07-17T14:28:45.9489139Z</DT>
      <S N="name">myName</S>
      <S N="text">myText</S>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>

I now reimport the CliXml
$m2 = Import-CliXml message.xml

and as expected I get a Deserialized.myMessage
$m2 | Get-Member

   TypeName : Deserialized.myMessage

Name           MemberType Definition
----           ---------- ----------
GetType        Method     type GetType()
ToString       Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider), string IFormattable.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
name           Property   System.String {get;set;}
text           Property   System.String {get;set;}
WhenCreatedUTC Property   System.DateTime {get;set;}

that I can cast it into a [myMessage] to get back the computed WhenCreated property
$m3 = [myMessage](Import-CliXml message.xml)
$m3 | Get-Member

   TypeName : myMessage

Name           MemberType     Definition
----           ----------     ----------
Equals         Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode    Method         int GetHashCode()
GetType        Method         type GetType()
ToString       Method         string ToString()
name           Property       string name {get;set;}
text           Property       string text {get;set;}
WhenCreatedUTC Property       datetime WhenCreatedUTC {get;set;}
WhenCreated    ScriptProperty System.Object WhenCreated {get= $this.WhenCreatedUTC.toLocalTime() ;}

I then try to teach Powershell to automatically do the cast for me using
Update-TypeData -TypeName myMessage -TargetTypeForDeserialization myMessage -Force

but this change absolutely nothing. the imported message desperatly stays of type Deserialized.myMessage and does not have the computed property.
what am I missing? isn't -TargetTypeForDeserialization intended to recreate the original object when deserialized?

You need to specify the deserialized type name in order to enact the conversion back to myMessage after deserialization:
Update-TypeData -TypeName Deserialized.myMessage -TargetTypeForDeserialization myMessage -Force


(facepalm) of course! how dumb I am! thank a lot :)
